# secure include files

Tags: php, security, include

I'd like to know the BEST solution to secure includes files.
For now my solution is this :

in the index file :

```
define('KEY','security');
include('s.php';
```

s.php :

```
if(KEY!='security') exit;
```

Comment: just because I'm paranoid I'd use `!==` instead of `!=`. In general I'd always use `===` and `!==` unless I have a specific reason not to since with the php type conversion rules it's easy to make mistakes with normal `==`.

Answer (score 1):

Most cases of similar code don't even check for a known value of key, but just check if it is defined.

For example Mediawiki uses this in include files:

```
<?php
if( !defined( 'MEDIAWIKI' ) ) {
    die( 1 );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
order deny,allow
deny from all
allow from 127.0.0.1
```

put this .htaccess in the include files seems to be a neat solution..

Comment: I wouldn't use that exclusively. I've had situations where a mis-configured webserver(or just after switching to another webserver) ignores .htaccess. Defense in depth with DEFINE guards is a good idea.

Comment: Some HTTP daemons do not support that and that's actually pretty dangerous to rely upon on.

Answer (score 0):

The best way would be to not put protected files under the document root (public_html, www, htdocs, etc). You can always include PHP files from the outside of the document root:

/home/user/public_html/index.php:

```
<?php

include('../include.php');
// /home/user/include.php -- not accessible!
```

Comment: Unfortunately that's not always possible. In particular if you distribute the software to others(it makes the setup too hard to get correct) or in some shared-hosting scenarios.