# How can I prevent users from accessing include files?

Tags: php, apache, include

I am using apache server. 
Is there a way to prevent users from accessing my include files directly ?
But only allow the server the access to those ?

Comment: possible duplicate of [secure include files](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3472956/secure-include-files)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way is to have the include files outside of the directory the site is served from.  For example:

```
/
    includes/somefile.php
    http/index.php
```

So the Web site is served from http/, but includes are outside of that directory, meaning no one can access them directly from a Web browser, but your scripts can include them like this:

```
<?php
require_once '../includes/somefile.php';
[...]
```

Answer (score 2):

Put them in a directory outside of the web root.

i.e. if `index.php` is in `/var/www/domain.com/www`, put the includes in `/var/www/domain.com/includes` or something.

Answer (score 2):

Do not put the include files under the document root (i.e. outside the file tree that apache delivers to the user).