# How do I prevent public access to php include files?

Tags: php, include

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [APACHE, prevent users from accessing include files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7704952/apache-prevent-users-from-accessing-include-files)

How do I prevent public access to php include files?

Let's say that I have a header.php, footer.php, a folder with multiple include files and I don't want users to access them directly by typing the filenames in the address bar. What is the best way to prevent this?

Thank you for your help

Comment: As usual, if you don't want to give people access to a file, don't put it into a public document tree. Put it somewhere outside the site's document root. PHP doesn't work at the URL level, and can access files anywhere on the server.

Comment: Sorry for the duplicate. And thanks for the info, I didn't think I could do that - put the includes outside the site's document root. Good to know.

Answer (score 0):

Move them outside of the web root.

Eg my web root is htdocs

```
.
├── htdocs
└── php
```

And php is outside of it

I include files like this

```
<?php
   include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../php/prepend.php");
   include($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "/../php/common.inc");
```